# How to Parallelize a simple MapAt?

Tags: parallelization, map

I have a simple map I would like to parallelize (4x speedup for my 4 cores):

```
testData = ResourceData["MNIST", "TestDataset"] // Normal;
encode[i_Image] := BaseEncode @ ExportByteArray[i, "PNG"];
AbsoluteTiming[result = MapAt[encode, testData, {All, "Image"}];]
(* => {57.9009, Null} *)
```

Unfortunately, wrapping `MapAt` with `Parallelize` doesn't work:

```
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[encode];
AbsoluteTiming[result = Parallelize @ MapAt[encode, testData, {All, "Image"}];]
```

[image]

Is there a simple workaround I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure about `MapAt`. Is `testData` is available to the parallel kernels? Check `ParallelEvaluate[testData[[1]]]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace your `MapAt` with a `ParallelMap`. I haven't investigated, why your `Parallelize` doesn't work, but this version here runs only some seconds on 12 cores:

```
testData = ResourceData["MNIST", "TestDataset"] // Normal;

encode[i_Image] := BaseEncode@ExportByteArray[i, "PNG"];
encode[ass_Association] := Association[ass, "Image" -> encode[ass["Image"]]]

ParallelMap[encode, testData];
```

The *trick*, if you like to call it so, is to provide a version of `encode` that directly converts an `Association` into the form you want by replacing the image with its encoded form.

[image]